# Not Receiving RabbitMQ Blocked Connection Notifications

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm attempting to register a `BlockedListener` on an AMQP `CachingConnectionFactory` to process notifications of connections entering/leaving a Blocked state. Unfortunately I'm never receiving any events.

In my Java client I'm using:

- `org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:2.1.11.RELEASE`
- `com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.4.3`

My Rabbit server is using the docker image `rabbitmq:3-management` which maps to `3.8.2` and `Erlang 22.2.4`

This is the code snippet I'm using to connect to rabbit and register the listener.

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory rmqConnectionFactory = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory();
rmqConnectionFactory.useNio();
rmqConnectionFactory.setHost(rabbitmqHost);
rmqConnectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitmqUsername);
rmqConnectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitmqPassword);
rmqConnectionFactory.setPort(rabbitmqPort);
rmqConnectionFactory.setVirtualHost(rabbitmqVirtualHost);

CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(rmqConnectionFactory);
cachingConnectionFactory.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Connection connection) {
    log.info("New connection: {}", connection);
    connection.getDelegate().addBlockedListener(new BlockedListener() {
      @Override
      public void handleBlocked(String s) {
        log.warn("Connection {} entered a blocked state with message {}", connection, s);
      }
      @Override
      public void handleUnblocked() {
        log.info("Connection {} left a blocked state", connection);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I get log entries from

```
log.info("New connection: {}", connection);
```

But not from

```
log.warn("Connection {} entered a blocked state with message {}", connection, s);
```

or

```
log.info("Connection {} left a blocked state", connection);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Now tell us, please, how do you block that connection to let the framework to initiate that `blocked` event: https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html

Comment: I've found a few ways to trip the condition; the simplest (most direct) I've found is to execute this command inside the container `rabbitmqctl set_vm_memory_high_watermark 0.01` (where `0.01` is small enough to be less than current memory usage)

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out; the above code/setup is *correct* however; Rabbit doesn't send the event until you attempt to publish a message on that connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using RabbitMQ server 3.7 in docker, but I can see that my `rabbitmq_amqp1_0` is not enabled. The [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/connection-blocked.html) says:

> We have introduced an AMQP 0-9-1 protocol extension in which the broker sends to the client a connection.blocked method when the connection gets blocked, and connection.unblocked when it is unblocked.

Perhaps you install a `rabbitmq_amqp0_9` plugin? I think the protocols `1_0` and `0_9` are different.

```
root@ffb673602565:/# rabbitmq-plugins list
Listing plugins with pattern ".*" ...
 Configured: E = explicitly enabled; e = implicitly enabled
 | Status: * = running on rabbit@ffb673602565
 |/
[  ] rabbitmq_amqp1_0                  3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache       3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_http        3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_event_exchange           3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_federation               3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_jms_topic_exchange       3.7.11
[E*] rabbitmq_management               3.7.11
[e*] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_aws       3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_common    3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_consul    3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_etcd      3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s       3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_random_exchange          3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_recent_history_exchange  3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_sharding                 3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_top                      3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_trust_store              3.7.11
[e*] rabbitmq_web_dispatch             3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt                 3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_web_mqtt_examples        3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.7.11
[  ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.7.11
```